# error: RPC failed; curl 56 Send failure: Connection was aborted

Tags: git, git-push

[image: Проблемс]

Пытаюсь залить большой проект (40гб) на гит. На протяжении уже 5 дней разные ошибки. Решил попробовать через приложение гитхаба, вместе Гит Бэша. Тут уже опять новые ошибкиииии, который раньше не было. Похожие проблемс уже были и в Гит бэш, читал другие статейки на эту тему, ничего разумеется не помогло :)))

Comment: 40 гигабайт? там что, фильмы? в любом случае, похоже, что Вы используете заливку через http. А тут вполне могут быть ограничения самого curl или сервера с той стороны (очень вероятно, что есть файл размером больше 2 гигабайт, к примеру. А такие случаи нужно аккуратно настроить).  Я бы для начала попробовал перейти на ssh подключение, а там будет понятно. Также явно уточнил у самого гитхаба, смогут ли они такое принять. Скорее за все, нужно будет отдельно настраивать/доплачивать

Answer (score 0):

Подробностей в вопросе мало, потому привожу лишь общие соображения без конкретики.

> большой проект (40гб)

- Eсли вы пытаетесь отправить свой проект на сервер github.com, то на этом сервере есть [ограничения как по общему размеру хранилища, так и по размеру отдельных файлов](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/what-is-my-disk-quota) (подобные ограничения существуют и на других аналогичных сайтах, подробности уточняйте в соответствующей документации этих сайтов). по ссылке описаны рекомендации — как поступить в такой ситуации. отмечу лишь пару моментов:

  - Eсли ваш проект является лишь «форком» уже существующего на сервере, то имеет смысл через веб-интерфейс создать свой «форк», ваше локальное хранилище привязать к этому «форку», и тогда отправляться командой push будут только ваши локальные доработки
  - Большие файлы (в подавляющем большинстве случаев содержащие не исходные тексты, а просто набор байтов) стоит хранить отдельно от файлов с исходными текстами (например, с помощью [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com))
- Eсли вы пытаетесь отправить свой проект на свой собственный сервер, про который вам точно известно, что на нём нет ограничений ни на общий размер хранилища, ни на размер отдельных файлов, то ошибка может быть вызвана нестабильностью работы сети, связывающей ваш компьтер с сервером. в таком случае имеет смысл попробовать скопировать хранилище:

  - либо «как есть»
  - либо в виде архива с файлами
  - либо в виде [bundle](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle)

  Bоспользовавшись при этом:

  - либо сторонним сервером (типа dropbox.com)
  - либо протоколом, позволяющим возобновлять прерванную передачу информации (rsync, например)

A затем уже произвести отправку непосредственно на самой машине с сервером (либо просто скопировать файлы и каталоги хранилища в нужное место).